# Questions about SQL and PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've been doing some learning on Codecademy for SQL and related things.
I want to make a python based database using PostgreSQL and SQLAlchemy.

However, when I try to make my own database with SQL the syntax clearly does not work in a python IDE and I don't understand where I am supposed to actually write the SQL database code.
Codecademy says to download 'Postbird' but it seems to be a GUI without the ability to actually write any code.

Codecademy teaches the basics of SQLAlchemy but I am not clear on whether SQLAlchemy is a replacement for writing a database in SQL or if it is an interface to a SQL database.

Can someone please clear up my confusion? I can't seem to find a clear answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: The database is where the data is stored, and is separate from the app, where the logic happens.

Comment: Where do I write the database though? This is where my confusion lies. Codecademy taught me the syntax but gave me confusing direction on where and how to use it.
As stated above it tells me to use postbird which has no IDE and I'm thinking maybe I'm supposed to use SQLAlchemy instead of PostgreSQL but I have no idea at all.

Comment: Do you already have a database server installed in your computer or in a server somewhere? (you can install PostgreSQL or MariaDB for free). Alternatively, you can play for free in MySQL using https://db4free.net/. Register for a free database to play around. No service or warranty included!

Comment: I have ngrok and I've installed PostgreSQL . I just have no idea where to apply the syntax.
PostgreSQL  installation doesn't seem to have an IDE. I also don't understand the purpose of Postbird.
I would think Codecademy would tell me something as important as this so I want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding something they told me.

Comment: PostgreSQL is a great database, and of course it comes with no IDE or UI (it's a server). You can download "pgadmin" to: 1) Create a database; 2) Create a user/pass credentials. Once that is done you can connect to it (from your app or other tools) on port `5432` and run all your SQL there.

Comment: 1) codecademy does not sound particularly useful. 2) Postgres is a client server architecture so you need some sort of client to connect and work with it. 3) My personal choice is the command line client that ships with Postgres [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). 3) To work with SQLAlchemy you will need some sort of Python client/IDE. My favorite for this `ipython`. You can install in `virtenv` with  `pip install ipython`.